# How do I edit a non-spam question that is miss-interpreted as spam?

Tags: support, bug

I am trying to adjust the tags on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777672/re-sub-gives-different-results-than-re-findall. It should include ibm-midrange, and exclude rpg. Unfortunately when I try to save my changes I get a popup telling me that it looks like spam. I have been unable to edit the message to avoid this popup even though the question is obviously not spam. How do I get this to go through?

Answer (score 2):

That is probably happening due to the Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters that are not expected on Stack Overflow but are known for being used by spammers.

I've gone ahead and made a tag-only edit, matching what you wanted to achieve.

I didn't bother to check if the offending characters can be missed. In that case removing those characters would also have solved the issue.

If you had been able to make that edit, so would have the spammers. I'm not sure if full edit privilege (which you get at 2K reputation) lift this check as well.

Comment: Interestingly, the OP was able to put the Asian characters into the post without getting a spam notification...

Comment: @honk the restriction is *Shog-able*, so one moment it is there, then be gone for weeks, and only returns when the Unicorns howl to the full moon ...

Comment: Oi, I just noticed, that the post is more than 3 weeks old. In the context of your comment, that might explain a lot. Happy howling ;)