# Why does the system say that my 'About me' section looks like spam?

Tags: support, profile-page, spam

I tried to update my profile on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't save the profile. The system says that it looks like spam.

Is it because I'm including Japanese and Spanish text?

### P.S.

- What did you tried to put?

I tried to put "I live in countryside" on my profile, but my profile is already including Spanish and Japanese.

- Why is your profile including Spanish and Japanese?

That is why I can update my profile on other sites.

Comment: Foreign characters seem to be a problem with the spam filter on this site, yes. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339256/1016716) or [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327380/1016716) for example.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263724/309650

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the text which you were trying to put in your about?

Comment: @Ashish I tried to add "I live in the countryside", but my profile is already including Spanish and Japanese.

Comment: Could be. Might be a help if you included your section..

Comment: One improve to your Spanish text: "No hablo bien el español, hablo japonés, me gusta aprender idiomas, programar y no creo en ninguna religión."... I think...

Comment: @Sxntk I rewrite it on other site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tweaked the expression here; it should let you edit your profile now (though we may have to reinstate this if spammers figure out a way to abuse it in a sufficiently-annoying fashion).